# Do I have to restart Apache when creating a new database?

Tags: mysql, linux, database, apache, debian

I just read a Tutorial on how to create a new Database in MySQL via Putty on a Linux-Debian-Server. These are the steps which are mentioned:

1) login to MySQL

2) create a user which is bind to my new DB

3) logout and login with the user created before

4) create my new DB

5) restart apache

Do I really have to restart Apache? I mean, I just want to create a new Test-DB beside my real (productive-)DB. I fear this step, because I don't know what services I will have to restart, too. And I am a total noob on Linux.

Comment: No, you don't have to. Apache and MySQL are independent, you just connect from your web-Application to the MySQL-Server.

Comment: Incorrect. Do you need restart apache. For MySQL users actions you need  FLUSH PRIVILEGES, not restart apache. Also tutorial it's very confused. You not need exit on mysql. Create user, create new DB, assign permission for this user to new db, flush privileges. It's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mysql and Apache are two services different. Also on your steeps there're some misconceptions.

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'newuser'@'localhost';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

It's all steeps what you need for create aun user of mysql, create a database, and assign permission for this user to use this datase on localhost

Answer (score 0):

Mysql and apache are 2 independent applications, creating a database in mysql does not affect apache, as creating for example a new virtual directory in apache will not affect mysql either.